# Android ViewModel onCleared() called too late

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-viewmodel, jetpack-compose-navigation

From my understanding of [navigation graph scoped view models](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel), their `onCleared` method should get called immediately when the associated navigation graph is popped from the navigation stack. What I'm seeing is that it takes a couple more navigate calls, until `onCleared` is actually getting called.

Inside MainActivity.kt:

```
val swipeDismissableNavController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()

swipeDismissableNavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    try {
        controller.getBackStackEntry("chat")
    } catch(e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not on stack")
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Route: " + destination.route)
})

SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = swipeDismissableNavController,
    startDestination = "home"
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = "messages",
        route = "chat"
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "messages"
        ) { 
            val backStackEntry = remember { swipeDismissableNavController.getBackStackEntry("chat") }
            val chatViewModel: ChatViewModel = viewModel(backStackEntry)
            
            ...
        }
        
        composable(
            route = "image"
        ) { 
            val backStackEntry = remember { swipeDismissableNavController.getBackStackEntry("chat") }
            val chatViewModel: ChatViewModel = viewModel(backStackEntry)
            
            ...
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Inside ChatViewModel.kt

```
class ChatViewModel(): ViewModel() {
    ...
    
    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "init")
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.d(TAG, "onCleared")
    }
}
```

What I am observing is the following behavior:
When I navigate to `chat`, the view model is correctly created printing `init`. By navigating inside the `chat` graph, the view model instance is correctly reused.
However, when I'm navigating out of the `chat` graph, I'm seeing that `Not on stack` is getting printed, but `onCleared` is not. Only after some additional navigations, `onCleared` is getting printed eventually.

Does anyone have an idea why `onCleared` is getting called delayed?

The print stack looks something like:

```
Not on Stack
Route: home

Route: messages
init

Not on Stack
Route: home
** (THIS IS WHERE I WOULD EXPECT TO SEE onCleared) **

Not on Stack
Route: settings

Not on Stack
Route: home
onCleared
```

However, if I'm doing more navigations inside the `chat` graph, `onCleared` is getting called correctly:

```
Not on Stack
Route: home

Route: messages
init

Route: image

Route: messages

Route: image

Route: messages

Route: image

Route: messages

Not on Stack
Route: home
onCleared
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Compose hooks up viewModels by default to the nearest Fragment or Activity in view hierarchy which controls lifetime of those viewModels in same way as it would be non - compose world.

I have solved the issue in my case by using custom ViewModelOwner + DisposableEffect:

```
if (selectedParkingAreaId != null) {
    val viewModelStore = remember(selectedParkingAreaId) { ViewModelStore() }
    DisposableEffect(selectedParkingAreaId) {
        onDispose { viewModelStore.clear() }
    }

    val viewModel: WheelScreenViewModel =
        viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = { viewModelStore })
    
    ...
}
```

Then when `selectedParkingAreaId` is null the `if` section is being excluded from composition which fires `DisposableEffect.onDispose{...}` which clears `ViewModelStore` which calls WheelScreenViewModel.onCleared.

Not super elegant, but functional.